# xepersian and qtree incompatibility?

Tags: qtree, xepersian

I am a linguist and want to display trees. I tried the the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xepersian}

\usepackage{qtree}

\begin{document}
\begin{latin}
gshjgsdjgsad

\begin{figure}

\Tree
[.case nom gen dat acc ]

\end{figure}

\end{latin}

\end{document}
```

I called it with `xelatex`. This works without the `xepersian` package loaded but fails with the package loaded. With the package loaded, I just get the lines, but the words (case nom gen dat acc) are missing.

I would be glad if you had any suggestions for me.

Comment: Make a bug report in https://github.com/vafa/xepersian/issues but I do not promise updating xepersian package unless there is some donations to the project.

Answer (score 2):

switch to LM or another font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\newfontface\LM{Latin Modern Roman}
\begin{document}
\begin{latin}
gshjgsdjgsad

\begin{figure}
\LM\Tree[.case nom gen dat acc ]
\end{figure}
\end{latin}

\end{document}
```